How do I configure my library to best support static builds of dependent projects?
Suppose I am developing the libfoo library, written in a compiled language, and am using CMake to configure its build. This library itself depends on another library, libbar. Thus, if someone else is building the MyApp application, which uses my library, they have to have link both against libfoo and libbar (e.g. specify both -lfoo and -lbar).
Suppose the MyApp developer also uses CMake. And they write:
find_package(foo REQUIRED)

with my exported CMakeLists configuration files in the CMake search path. Naturally, this will propagate the dependency on libbar and result in the appropriate linking.
Now, suppose the MyApp developer wants to produce a static binary. Can they easily achieve that, both w.r.t. libfoo and to libbar? If not, what do I, as the library developer, need to do in my library's CMakeLists, to ensure that MyApp completes a proper configuration of a fully static build?

Have you run into difficulty in getting your library, with its dependency, to accommodate client static builds? An MRE exemplifying your best approach, and its shortcomings, would allow answers not to cover possible pitfalls it doesn't have.
